# .net framework API: create an API to create new incident with customer type field in microsoft dynamics 365

Tags: c#, .net, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I created an API .NET framework to connect microsoft dynamics 365 then I would like to do CRUD on the incident entity that contains a Customer field (which refers to the Account entity).

```
  public void SaveIncident(IncidentEntityModels objIncidentModel)
        {
            using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("MyConnectionString"))
            {
                
                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
                {
                    EntityName = "account",
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("accountid", "name")
                };
                List<EntityReference> info = new List<EntityReference>() ;
                EntityCollection Client = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                if (Client != null && Client.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    EntityReference itm;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Client.Entities.Count; i++)
                    {
                        itm = new EntityReference();
                        if (Client[i].Id != null)
                            itm.Id = Client[i].Id;
                        if (Client[i].Contains("name") && Client[i]["name"] != null)
                            itm.Name = Client[i]["name"].ToString();

                        itm.LogicalName = "account";
                        info.Add(itm);
                    }
                }
             
                Entity IncidentEntity = new Entity("incident");
                if (objIncidentModel.IncidentID != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    IncidentEntity["incidentid"] = objIncidentModel.IncidentID;
                }
                IncidentEntity["title"] = objIncidentModel.TitreIncident;
                IncidentEntity["customerid"] = info;
                IncidentEntity["description"] = objIncidentModel.Description;
         

                    if (objIncidentModel.IncidentID == Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        objIncidentModel.IncidentID = service.Create(IncidentEntity);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        service.Update(IncidentEntity);
                    }

            }
```

What do I need to add for this code to work?

Comment: The way it is written now, incidents will be created for bunch of accounts. Pls test the code, lemme know if any problem - I just answered in mobile :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `customerid` is a lookup/EntityReference and it cannot take List or Entity collection. Also your code is querying all accounts using `RetrieveMultiple`, you have to apply `filter` to get only particular account if you want.

```
public void SaveIncident(IncidentEntityModels objIncidentModel)
    {
        using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("MyConnectionString"))
        {
            
            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "account",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("accountid", "name")
            };
           
            EntityCollection Client = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            if (Client != null && Client.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                EntityReference itm;
                for (int i = 0; i < Client.Entities.Count; i++)
                {
                    itm = new EntityReference();
                    if (Client[i].Id != null)
                        itm.Id = Client[i].Id;
                    if (Client[i].Contains("name") && Client[i]["name"] != null)
                        itm.Name = Client[i]["name"].ToString();

                    itm.LogicalName = "account";

            Entity IncidentEntity = new Entity("incident");
            if (objIncidentModel.IncidentID != Guid.Empty)
            {
                IncidentEntity["incidentid"] = objIncidentModel.IncidentID;
            }
            IncidentEntity["title"] = objIncidentModel.TitreIncident;
            IncidentEntity["customerid"] = itm;
            IncidentEntity["description"] = objIncidentModel.Description;
     

                if (objIncidentModel.IncidentID == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    objIncidentModel.IncidentID = service.Create(IncidentEntity);
                }
                else
                {
                    service.Update(IncidentEntity);

                }
            }
         

        }

    }
```

Comment: @ProgrammingLover, very glad. pls accept the answer :)